# How to convert multiple columns to one column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have result like below:

```
level_1_node level_2_node level_3_node level_4_node 
Node 1       Node2        Node 3       Node 4
```

I want to convert it to:

```
Node
Node 1
Node 2
Node 3
Node 4
```

How to do it?

Comment: Google for unpivot operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`unpivot`](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=506) table operator:

```
select value
from tablename
unpivot 
(
  value
  for node in (level_1_node, 
               level_2_node, 
               level_3_node, 
               level_4_node)
);
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b7d5f/5)

Answer (score 3):

you can use **[Union](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm)**

```
select "level_1_node" as Node from Table1
union
select "level_2_node" as Node from Table1
union
select "level_3_node" as Node from Table1
union
select "level_4_node" as Node from Table1
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c1d64/2)**

Comment: Thank you Luv, your answer is workable, but I want a more "elegant" solution since the level is non-static.